# How do I convert a Stack of booleans to byte value?

Tags: java, stack, boolean, byte

In this problem I take characters  '0' , and '1'
I also can take strings like "0011001" 
I have them stored in a buffer but I need to change the true and false into bytes like 1 and 0.

{I need help in the OutputByte method.}

```
public class BitOutputStream {      
    Stack<Boolean> buffer;
    OutputStream os;

    BitOutputStream(OutputStream file) {
        buffer = new Stack<Boolean>();
        os = file;
    }

    public void WriteBit(char bit) throws IOException {
        if (bit == '0') buffer.push(false);    
        else buffer.push(true);
    }    

    //Needs to take care both of the scenarios
    public void WriteBit(String bit) throws IOException {
        if (bit == "0") buffer.push(false);    
        else buffer.push(true);    
        OutputByte();
    }    

    //When the close() method is called, output whatever bits are in the buffer (even if less than 8).
    public void close() throws IOException {    
        os.close();    
    }

    //Turning boolean buffer to byte
    private void OutputByte() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to write if then else in a proper way. It will make your code 10 times easier to read and it will stop you falling into a bad habbit.

Comment: Do you need to use a stack? You maybe could make use of a bitfield / an array of bitfields: `byte[] bitfields` which would then allow you to read the different `bytes`